# Display multiple markers in the mapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

I'm working with google-maps and i created this function

```
  func addMarker(place:EClass) {

            guard let coordinates = place.location  else {
                return
            }

            self.destination = coordinates

            marker = GMSMarker()
            marker?.position = coordinates
            marker?.title = place.name
            marker?.map = mapView
            mapView.selectedMarker = marker

        }
```

to add a marker in my mapView at the position of an object of type EClass; but in my case i need to show different markers on the mapView at the position of each elements of `var places: [EClass] = []`. To do this i tried to add something like this in my viewDidLoad

```
let srt = places

   srt.forEach { addMarker(place: $0) }
```

but it doesn't working, so how can i do?

this is my class EClass

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


private let geometryKey = "geometry"
private let locationKey = "location"
private let latitudeKey = "lat"
private let longitudeKey = "lng"
private let nameKey = "name"
private let vicinityKey = "vicinity"



class EClass: NSObject  {


    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var name: String?
    var vicinity: String?
    var placeId: String



    init(placeInfo:[String: Any]) {

        placeId = placeInfo["place_id"] as! String


        // coordinates
        if let g = placeInfo[geometryKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g[locationKey] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l[latitudeKey], let lng = l[longitudeKey] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }

        // name
        name = placeInfo[nameKey] as? String


        }
```

//UPDATE

```
static func getNearbyPlaces(by category:String, coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius:Int, token: String?, completion: @escaping (QNearbyPlacesResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {

    var params : [String : Any]

    if let t = token {
        params = [
            "key" : AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey,
            "pagetoken" : t,
        ]
    } else {
        params = [
            "key" : AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey,      
            "radius" : radius,
            "location" : "\(coordinates.latitude),\(coordinates.longitude)",
            "type" : category.lowercased()
        ]
    }

    Alamofire.request(searchApiHost, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)).responseJSON { response in

        if let error = response.error {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
        if let response = QNearbyPlacesResponse(dic : response.result.value as? [String : Any]) {
            completion(response, nil)
        }
        else {
            completion(nil, QNearbyPlacesResponseError.noParsingDone)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767500/place-multiple-markers-on-gmsmapview-swift/47952724#47952724

Comment: ok @KhawarIslam your answer it look perfect but sorry i'm a beginner and i'm little confused, in my  specific case the step 1 is ok because i have the model "EClass", the step 2 also because i have the array var places: [EClass] = [], in the step 3 and 4 can you give me a little example of what i have to do?

Comment: where is your data which you want to show in mapView? This data is come from web service?

Comment: i'm using google places API, i also updated the question to show you

Comment: @KhawarIslam in my mapView i want to add a marker for each element of var places: [EClass] = []

Comment: it is possible to share the code?

Comment: @KhawarIslam yes what do you need?

Comment: basically whole code, because first  will try to fix your bug, if not, then i optimize your code.